# Changing the ACL on a folder through Wscript.Shell within VBA

Tags: vba, file-system, windows

I have working VBA code in excel that changes a network folders permissions.

The code uses Wscript.Shell to run icacls commands but there are multiple instances of this command and each time it runs, it opens up a new shell window.

It would be interesting to see if there is a way of making the code more efficient by opening a single shell instance then go on to run each of the icacls commands.

```
Private Sub TestingPermissions()

Dim FSO
Dim MyFolder
Dim objShell

Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set MyFolder = FSO.GetFolder(Worksheets("Config").Range("D4").Value & ActiveSheet.Range("C21").Value)

Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")

' Take ownership and modify permission of folder
objShell.Run ("takeown /f " & """" & MyFolder & "\My Music""" & " /r /d y")
objShell.Run ("icacls " & """" & MyFolder & "\My Music""" & " /setowner mydomain\admin")
objShell.Run ("icacls " & """" & MyFolder & "\My Music""" & " /grant mydomain\StudentExam101:(OI)(CI)F /T")
objShell.Run ("icacls " & """" & MyFolder & "\My Music""" & " /grant mydomain\DAdmins:(OI)(CI)F /T")
objShell.Run ("icacls " & """" & MyFolder & "\My Music""" & " /grant mydomain\admin:(OI)(CI)F /T")
objShell.Run ("icacls " & """" & MyFolder & "\My Music""" & " /grant SYSTEM:(OI)(CI)F /T")
objShell.Run ("icacls " & """" & MyFolder & "\My Music""" & " /grant CREATOR OWNER:(OI)(CI)F /T")

End Sub
```

I thought I had found a part solution by combining the icalcs permissions all into one command but further testing and I realised it had not worked, but I will investigate this further anyway.

Comment: I'd put my commands into a file and then get the shell to run the commands in my file.

Comment: I was thinking about having the vba create the file with the commands and run it from there, but I decided to go this way as it seems a slightly cleaner solution as their are no external files to deal with.  The code shown is only a small part of what the vba script will do and it will be run many times with information updated pulled into the spread sheet from multiple sources.

Comment: Just a warning, this phrase `What I would like the code to be able to do ...` might make the question off-topic as it indicates either the code is not working as expected or this is a feature request, which we can't answer.

Comment: @pacmaninbw thanks for the tip, I'm more used to asking questions in stackoverflow so I will make a note of that. Now re-worded as: 'It would be interesting to see if there is a way of making the code more efficient'

Answer (score 6):

### CodeReview

Why use the `Scripting.FileSystemObject`?  `MyFolder` is just returning the folder name

> MyFolder = Worksheets("Config").Range("D4").Value & ActiveSheet.Range("C21").Value

I would also write a function to return the folder path and a second function to create the icacls commands.

### Fun Part: My Own Solution

The class below will create a self-deleting batch file.  Running it in silent mode will hide the command window.  The advantage of using a batch file is that you can add a pause that will allow you to inspect the results of your commands.

Note: pause will have no effect in silent mode and the files do not delete themselves immediately but they will automatically delete after a short time.

[image: Command Window]

---

### Class: BatchFile

```
Attribute VB_Name = "BatchFile"

Option Explicit
Public FileText As String
Private Const DeleteCommand As String = "DEL ""%~f0"""

Public Sub AppendLine(Text As String)
    If Len(FileText) > 0 Then FileText = FileText & vbNewLine
    FileText = FileText & Text
End Sub

Public Sub AddICacls(ByVal FolderName As String, ByVal Parameters As String)
    AppendLine "icacls " & Chr(34) & FolderName & Chr(34) & Parameters
End Sub

Public Sub Execute(SilentMode As Boolean)
    Dim FilePath As String
    FilePath = getTempBatchFileName

    CreateFile FilePath

    Dim oShell As Object
    Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

    If SilentMode Then
        oShell.Run Chr(34) & FilePath & Chr(34), 0
    Else
        oShell.Run Chr(34) & FilePath & Chr(34)
    End If

    Set oShell = Nothing
End Sub

Private Sub CreateFile(FilePath As String)
    Dim Text As String
    Text = FileText & vbNewLine & DeleteCommand

    Dim FileNumber As Long
    FileNumber = FreeFile
    Open FilePath For Output As FileNumber
    Print #FileNumber, Text
    Close FileNumber

    Debug.Print Text
End Sub


Private Function getTempBatchFileName() As String
    Dim n As Long
    Dim FilePath As String

    Do
        n = n + 1
        FilePath = Environ("Temp") & "\" & n & ".bat"
    Loop While Len(Dir(FilePath)) > 0

    getTempBatchFileName = FilePath
End Function
```

---

### Usage

```
Sub RunICalcs()
    Const DebugMode As Boolean = True

    Dim Batch As New BatchFile
    Dim FolderName As String
    FolderName = getFolderPath

    Batch.AddICacls FolderName, " /r /d y"
    Batch.AddICacls FolderName, " /setowner mydomain\admin"
    Batch.AddICacls FolderName, " /grant mydomain\StudentExam101:(OI)(CI)F /T"
    Batch.AddICacls FolderName, " /grant mydomain\DAdmins:(OI)(CI)F /T"
    Batch.AddICacls FolderName, " /grant mydomain\admin:(OI)(CI)F /T"
    Batch.AddICacls FolderName, " /grant SYSTEM:(OI)(CI)F /T"
    Batch.AddICacls FolderName, " /grant CREATOR OWNER:(OI)(CI)F /T"

    If DebugMode Then
        Batch.AppendLine "pause"
        Batch.Execute False
    Else
        Batch.AppendLine "pause"
        Batch.Execute True
    End If
End Sub

Function getFolderPath() As String
    getFolderPath = Worksheets("Config").Range("D4").Value & ActiveSheet.Range("C21").Value
End Function
```